# Java uses how many processors available in OS?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have deleted the old question, as here is the question which is more clear.
If any java process is started on a multi-core CPU, then which core will this java process be assigned to ? is this OS specific? If java process starts many threads then will other cores get chance to run these threads or only the core which started java process will handle those threads?

Looking for constructive answers.

Comment: This question is not well written.

Comment: http://architects.dzone.com/news/building-multi-core-ready-java

Comment: I've added some examples to my answer.  You can ask questions in the comments if you've like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If any OS is multi-processor, then JVM uses all of them or one of them?

On most modern hardware architectures, the JVM will make use of all CPUs/cores made available to it by the OS.

> And As processors ahve different memory context so their corresponding memory threads will also have different memory contexts, so they will not be having concurrency issues?

Uh, no?  I'm not sure what you are asking here but the whole issue with concurrency is that CPUs have their own cache memory.  This is why memory synchronization and locking is so important.  A thread may make local changes to its cached memory or its cached memory may get invalidated because of changes made to central storage by other threads.  So there certainly are "concurrency issues" with multi-processor and different memory "contexts".

---

Edit:

> Here is the main doubt i have: If there are 4 processes being used by JVM (P1,P2,P3,P4) then threads running under one process will face concurrency issue, Thread T1 under P1, and thread T2 under P2 will never have concurrency issue as they have different memory contexts. Am i right or wrong?

You are wrong.  The JVM will schedule your 4 user threads and the other background threads (gc, finalizer, jmx, etc) on the 4 processors in contention with other processes running on the same operating system.  At points in time, the JVM may be using all 4 processors or may be using no processors depending on the other processes running on the OS.

If T1 and T2 are on different processors then they can be running simultaneously.  None of the threads will have concurrency issues unless they share data.  If T1 makes changes to an object that T2 is also using, T2 may or may not see these changes depending on what synchronization is being used.  This memory synchronization is one of the big problems with multi-threaded programming.  For example:

```
 static Integer sharedValue = 1;
 ...
 // thread T1 changes the shared value
 sharedValue = 2;
 ...
 // thread T2 reads the shared value later
 // it is unknown whether this will print 1 or 2
 System.out.println("shared = " + sharedValue);
```

If T2 is swapped out and T3 runs on the same processor there may actually be *less* concurrency issues since they are both using the same CPU cache but you still need to worry about *locking*.  For example, if the T2 task does a `++` which seems atomic but is actually 3 operations (get, increment, store), it might get interrupted after the increment but before the store and may overwrite T3's increment:

```
 static int counter = 0;
 ...
 // thread T2
 // 3 operations: get, increment, store
 // this thread might be interrupted in the middle causing a ++ to be lost
 counter++;
 ...
 // thread T3
 // 3 operations: get, increment, store
 // this thread might be interrupted in the middle causing a ++ to be lost
 counter++;
 ...
 // later on, even if T2 and T3 have completed, you may see the counter as 1 or 2
 System.out.println("counter = " + counter);
```

So locking is an issue even regardless of whether your threads are running on multiple or a single processor system.  See here for a [better example of non-atomic operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28programming%29#Example_atomic_operation).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to understand the distinction between *threads* and *parallelism*.

- Threads are an execution primitive, in which instructions are run on a CPU
- Parallelism is the potential for multiple threads to execute simultaneously

As an implementation detail, the JVM runs several threads for internal purposes. For example, the garbage collector operates on a separate thread from your code. Similarly, your code and libraries you consume may spawn any number of threads as part of their own implementation. Whether they will be run *in parallel* is another matter.

The OS is responsible for allocating CPU cores to threads so that they may be run, and these will ultimately limit the potential parallelism of your programs.

And yes, concurrency issues do exist because threads are inherently evil.

Answer (score 0):

> If any OS is multi-processor, then JVM uses all of them or one of them?

The JVM will use as many cores as the operating system lets it use ... up to the number of runnable threads.

> I am asking this because in a single processor, only one thread will be running at one time, so If there are 4 processors then 4 threads will be running at that time?

**Up to** 4 threads can be running simultaneously.  It depends on whether the threads are runnable, and whether the OS is prepared to schedule the application's threads on 4 cores.  (A system *typically* has other processes running as well as the JVM.)

> And As processors ahve different memory context so their corresponding memory threads will also have different memory contexts, so they will not be having concurrency issues?

Concurrency in Java is a *big topic*.  I recommend that you start by reading the Java Tutorial sections on the topic of [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).

Yes ... the different cores will share the same address space, you are correct that they will have different "memory contexts".  Specifically, they won't share register sets, and they may not share memory 1st / 2nd / 3rd level memory caches.  However, if you follow the rules for writing correct multi-threaded Java code, you should not have problems.  These rules (specified in the JLS as the Java Memory Model) make it crystal clear what a multi-threaded program can and cannot assume about when a change made by one thread is visible to another.

---

**UPDATE**

> Here is the main doubt i have: If there are 4 processes being used by JVM (P1,P2,P3,P4) then threads running under one process will face concurrency issue, Thread T1 under P1, and thread T2 under P2 will never have concurrency issue as they have different memory contexts. Am i right or wrong?

It is really hard to know what you mean, hence very difficult to tell if you are "right" or "wrong".

However:

- If you have 4 processes, then each process will run its own JVM.  There is one process per JVM.  No more, no less.
- Each threads belonging to one JVM (and hence one process), and cannot under normal circumstances<sup>1</sup> interfere with the threads belonging to another JVM.  Different processes DO NOT share memory contexts unless you do something to make it happen.  The OS makes sure of that the processes address spaces / memory contexts are separate.  (It would be a major security concern if it didn't!!)
- The threads belonging to one JVM *can* interfere with each other.  They *do* share the same virtual address space, though the sharing of memory is not perfect (see above about caching, etc).
- The mapping of threads to cores is dynamic; i.e. it can change by the millisecond.  However, the operating system makes sure that there is no unwanted leakage of memory contexts *between* threads in different processes.

<sup>1 - The picture is complicated when processes use "shared memory" segments.  However, you can't do this in pure Java, and even doing it in native code libraries within a JVM would be "difficult".</sup>